# Rails でいいねの create アクションが実行されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery, ajax

※他のサイトでも同様の質問を行っています。解決後はそれぞれ更新致します。よろしくお願いします。
https://teratail.com/questions/av2uvajgpeg8dy

#### 前提・実現したいこと

投稿された質問(post)に対して回答したコメント(comment)に非同期通信でいいね(good)を押す機能を実装したいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

設置したいいねリンクでcreateアクションが実行されません。
ビューは表示されており、検証ツールで以下のエラーが生じています。
画面のハートを押すとこのような挙動になります。

rails-ujs.js:216 POST http://localhost:3000/posts/1/comments/8/goods 404 (Not Found)
[image: イメージ説明]

#### 自分で調べたことや試したこと

質問に対してのいいねは以下記事を参考にし、実行できました。
https://qiita.com/max_3252/items/ca8f623563e26b6a8630

次はそのコードを流用する形でコメントへのいいねを実装しようとしましたが、このようなエラーが生じています。

404 not foundについて調べたところ、リンク切れやリダイレクトの設定ミスとありました。
リンク切れは無いとして、リダイレクトの設定ミスかと模索しました。

エラー内容にて、http://localhost:3000/posts/1/comments/8/goods とあり、
post_idやcomment_idの取得、methodの指定も行なっているので問題ないのでは...と思い、原因を掴めていません。

#### 使っているツールのバージョンなど補足情報

ruby: 3.0.2
rails: 6.0.4
jquery-rails: 4.4.0

---

#### 該当のソースコード

ルーティング

```
routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
（省略）
  resources :posts do
    resources :favorites, only: %i[create destroy]
    resources :comments, only: %i[create destroy] do
      resources :goods, only: %i[create destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

ビュー関連

```
app/views/goods/create.js.erb

$('#goods_buttons<%= @comment.id %>').html("<%= j(render partial: 'goods/good', locals: {post: @post, comment: @comment}) %>");
```

```
app/views/goods/destroy.js.erb

$('#goods_buttons<%= @comment.id %>').html("<%= j(render partial: 'goods/good', locals: {post: @post, comment: @comment}) %>");
```

```
app/views/goods/_good.html.erb

<% unless @comment.good_user(@current_user.id).blank? %>
    <%= link_to post_comment_good_path(post_id: @post.id, comment_id: comment.id), method: :delete, remote: true do %>
      <div class="vertical_good">
       <%= image_tag "icon_red_heart.png", size: '20x20' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to post_comment_goods_path(@post, comment), method: :post, remote: true do %>
      <div class="vertical_good">
        <%= image_tag "icon_heart.png", size: '20x20' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

```
app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb

<div class="p-comment__item">
  <p><%= simple_format(comment.comment) %></p>
  <div class="p-comment__bottomLine">
    <div id="goods_buttons<%= comment.id %>">
      <%= render partial: 'goods/good', locals: { post: @post, comment: comment } %>
    </div>
    <span><%= comment.created_at.to_s(:datetime_jp) %></span>
    <span><%= link_to '削除', post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: '削除してよろしいですか？' } %></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
app/views/posts/show.html.erb

（一部省略）
<div class="p-comment__list">
  <div class="p-comment_listTitle">コメント</div>
  <%= render @post.comments %>
</div>

<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { comment: @comment } %>
```

コントローラ

```
goods_controller.rb

class GoodsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: %i[create destroy]

  def create
    @good = Good.create(user_id: current.user_id, post_id: @post.id, comment_id: @comment.id)
  end

  def destroy
    good = Good.find_by(user_id: current.user_id, comment_id: comment.id)
    good.destroy
  end

  private

  def set_comment
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.find(comment_id: @post.id)
  end
end
```

```
comments_controller.rb

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    if comment.save
      flash[:notice] = 'コメントを投稿しました'
      redirect_to comment.post
    else
      flash[:comment] = comment
      flash[:error_messages] = comment.errors.full_messages
      redirect_back fallback_location: comment.post
    end
  end

  def destroy
    comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    comment.delete
    redirect_to comment.post, flash: { notice: 'コメントが削除されました' }
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :comment)
  end
end
```

```
posts_controller.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_target_post, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

（省略）
  
  def show
    @comment = Comment.new(post_id: @post.id)
  end

（省略）

  private

（省略）

  def set_target_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`goods_controller.rb`にある、

```rb
@comment = Comment.find(comment_id: @post.id)
```

ですが、`find`メソッドは引数にIDを取ります。ハッシュを渡しても動作しません。
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find
この際、`Comment`レコードが見つからないため、Railsは「リソースが見つからなかった」際に出すべき404のステータスコードを返します。

ここではコメントのIDがすでに分かっており（今ならば`8`）、それを使ってコメントの取得ができます。

```rb
@comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
```

と、ここまで書いていて気づいたのですが、Postを取得している

```rb
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

も、

```rb
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
```

に変更したほうがよいかもしれません。Railsの`params`に渡ってくる`id`関係の値がどのようなキーで取得できるかは`resources`の書き方によって変わってくるためです。

なお、

> 404 not foundについて調べたところ、リンク切れやリダイレクトの設定ミスとありました。
> リンク切れは無いとして、リダイレクトの設定ミスかと模索しました。

というのは一般的な理解ではあるのですが、Railsはデータベースからレコードを発見できなかったときに404を返すのは覚えておいてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！指摘いただいた箇所と`@good = Good.create(user_id: current_user.id, post_id: @post.id, comment_id: @comment)`からpost.id: @post_id を削除、`$('#goods_buttons<%= @comment.id %>').~`から @ を削除したところタイトルの404NotFoundが解決しました。違う箇所で問題が生じたのでそれはまた別の質問でさせていただきます。